# Elementary topology question about bases and topologies

Tags: general-topology

> Let $X$ be a topological space. Let $\mathscr{O}$ be the collection
>   of  open sets of $X$ with the following property: For each open $O
>  \subset  X$ and each $x \in O$, there exists and element $U \in
>  \mathscr{O}$   such that $x \in U \subset O $. Then $\mathscr{O}$ is a
>   basis for the  topology of $X$.

#### Attempted Solution:

Let $x \in X$ be arbitrary. Since $X$ is open trivially, then by the property of the collection $\mathscr{O}$, we have an open set $ U \in \mathscr{O}$ with $x \in U \subset X$. Next, choose $U_1,U_2 \in \mathscr{O}$ with $x \in U_1 \cap U_2 $. Since intersections of open sets are open, we have that $U_1 \cap U_2 \in \mathscr{O}$. Hence, we select an element $U \in \mathscr{O}$ such that $x \in U \subset U_1 \cap U_2 $.

So, $\mathscr{O}$ is a basis for the topology of $X$.

Is this a correct approach?

Def of Basis:

Let $X$ be a set. a basis for a toplogy of $X$ is a collection $\mathscr{B}$ of subsets of  $X$ such that

1. for each $x \in X$, there is $B \in \mathscr{B}$ such that $x \in B \subset X$.
2. If $B_1,B_2 \in \mathscr{B}$ with $x \in B_1 \cap B_2 $ then there is $B_3 \in \mathscr{B}$ such that $ x \in B_3 \subset B_1 \cap B_2 $.

Comment: There are a couple of ways to define *base* for a topology; which one are you using?

Comment: Prof. Brian I have updated my question with definition of basis.

Comment: not directly related but "topology" by james munkres is a very good book and has plenty of examples, great for general topology

Comment: Here $\mathscr{O}$ should not be called **the** collection of open sets, but **a** collection of open sets. If it is **the** collection of open sets then it is *automatically* a basis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It’s almost right. For the second part, where you have $U_1,U_2\in\mathscr{O}$, you can conclude that $U_1\cap U_2$ is open, since the intersection of finitely many open sets is open (and it is important that we’re intersecting only finitely many), but not that it’s in $\mathscr{O}$. Fortunately, you don’t need to have $U_1\cap U_2\in\mathscr{O}$: you merely need it to be open, since the hypothesis then guarantees you a $U\in\mathscr{O}$ such that $x\in U\subseteq U_1\cap U_2$.

In other words, it’s very much the right idea, but you didn’t express it entirely correctly.

Comment: Thank you professor Brian!

Comment: @FromCuba: You’re welcome!